# React Native - How to convert image path to file so that I can append and send the file down to server

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Upon successfully cropping an image on my React Native app, I am ending up with an object represented by the cropped image's path on the device.

My goal is to send this cropped image down to my server. I understand that before appending this object to send it to my node server, I need to first convert this path to its correspondent file format. So my question is how can I do so?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the snippet below:
Note: `headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', // this is important
          }` is important when send FormData to server

```js
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios"


export default function App() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState({});
  const cropImage =() =>{
    const uri = "your_image_uri"
    setImage({
      uri: uri,
      name: "image_name",
      type: 'image/png', // if you can get image type from cropping replace here
    });
  }

  const sendImageToServe = () =>{
    const formData = new FormData();
    if (image && Object.keys(image).length > 0) {
      formData.append('file', image);
      formData.append('Content-Type', 'image/png');
    }

    // using axios to send to swerver
    
    axiosIns1({
      baseURL: 'https://med-h.tech/cms/',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', // this is important
      },
      method: 'post',
      url: 'your_endpoint',
      data: formData,
    });
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

- Other way to send image to server is convert your image to base64String and then send as normal string